# How to select specific array using if else PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little guidance.The scenario is I want to display different outputs based on the array given. For example if the array have specific value it will show that data. I will show an example.

```
[{"ID":"1","NUMBER":"12345678"},{"numberno":"456789"}]
```

I already encode the array and the problem now only on the *if else*
. As you can see there is two different variable but I want to declare them AS same variable. This is the code that I have tried

```
if('ID'=true)
        { 
"SELECT NUMBER AS NO FROM DUAL UNION"
         }
else{
"SELECT numberno AS NUMBER FROM DUAL UNION"
}
```

So for example on the first array, there is `{"ID":"1","NUMBER":"12345678"}` so if there is `"ID"` exist in the array it will select `NUMBER` else will return `numberno` . I hope you understand my question. Thank you for your time. This is just an example. even if ur suggestion different , I will use it as reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> if(!ID OR ID='')
>
> {
>
> "SELECT numberno AS NUMBER FROM DUAL UNION"
>
> }
>
> elseif (ID){
>
> "SELECT NUMBER AS NO FROM DUAL UNION"
>
> }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).